# Корректная загрузка ZIP на FTP сервер

Tags: c#, ftp

Добрый день. 
Пытаюсь средствами C# загрузить ZIP архив на ftp севрер.

```
 FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/Temp/"+ fname);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("root","once");

            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"C:\pract.zip");
            byte[] fileContents = 
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Архивация проходит с помощью либы Ionic.  Сам архив создается корректно и открывается.
Но после передачи архива на сервер, архив становиться битым и при открытии выдает ошибку "Архив поврежден". Понимаю что проблема в кодировке, но не понимаю как правильно реализовать передачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `FileStream` вместо `StreamReader`.
Тогда будет что-то вроде:

```
FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(@"C:\pract.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var length=sourceStream.Length;
byte[] fileContents=new byte[length];
sourceStream.Read(fileContents, 0,length);
```

Comment: Ругается на эту строку sourceStream.Read(fileContents, 0,length); Ошибка преобразования long  в int

Comment: var length=(int)sourceStream.Length;  Помогло. Вопрос решен, спасибо!

Comment: может вы сможете помочь и по этой теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795261/c-ftp-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8